# If a variable is not assigned any value, what would its value be in AutoHotkey?

Tags: operators, undefined, autohotkey, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Consider the following code, what's the value of `Foo`?

```
Foo :=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **The colon-equals (:=) is an** expression assignment **[operator](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#operators)**. It
  assigns a value to a [variable](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Intro) (stores the result of an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) in a variable).
- Without a value assignment `Foo :=` makes no sense.
- You can assign an empty value ( or empty the content of the variable Foo) by setting it to `""`:

  `Foo := ""`

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is initialized (or it's value is set to empty with `foo:=""`), it's value is treated as an empty string `""`.

Edit: "initialized" is a misleading word, all variables are set to values of `""` (empty) by default in any case